# REACT AXIOS: I am working on a quiz that each questin has corresponding array of choices in that index in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I don't know if my code is correct or not, but it gives this error:

> TypeError: this.state.questions.map is not a function.

Why am I encountering this behavior?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Countdown from "react-countdown-now";

class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      ch: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://private-anon-c06008d89c-quizmasters.apiary-mock.com/questions")
      .then(response => {
        const { questions, ch } = response.data;
        this.setState({ questions, ch });
      });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.questions.map((que, index) => {
          <li>{que.questions} </li>;
          {
            this.ch[index].map(choice => <li>{choice}</li>);
          }
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what's inside `response.data`? Perhaps there is no array with questions.

Comment: In addition to what @IgorMalyk said above, you must also return your JSX from the render method.

Comment: It might be the case that API returns the data in a JSON like `{ questions: [], ... }` or `{ list: [], ...} ` When you assign `const { questions, ch } = response.data` you won't have `ch` because `response.data` is an axios prop which contains all the data payload. There is no `ch` property in the axios `response` object. I guess you need to look inside and just assign the right object within `response.data` to your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon looking at the network call response, I could see that response.data is of type array. But as you are applying object destructuring to obtain questions, it gets the value undefined. Hence the map at render fails as this.state.questions is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';

class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      ch: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://private-anon-c06008d89c-quizmasters.apiary-mock.com/questions')
      .then((response) => {
        const allQuestions = [];
        const allChoices = [];
        response.data.forEach(([{question, choices}]) => {
          allQuestions.push(question);
          allChoices.push(choices)
        })
        this.setState({ questions: allQuestions, ch: allChoices});
      });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.questions.map((que, index) => {
          <li>{que.questions} </li>;
          {
            this.ch[index].map((choice) => <li>{choice}</li>);
          }
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code in the example `const { questions, ch } = response.data; this.setState({ questions, ch });` assignes to the `this.state.questions` whatever is in the `response.data.questions`. Chances are there is no such property. That's why it is `undefined`.

Comment: Yup. In fact, response.data is of type array for this API call which will surely assign any object destructured variable with the value undefined.

Comment: ch is for the choices